# How to de-cypher structure of Selenium Scripts exported from IDE - NUnit Framework

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm new to writing test scripts so I apologize for my lack of understanding here, I'm certainly willing to learn though!

I've recorded a number of scripts in the Selenium IDE, but have found it lacking in flexibility (a reliance on static UI elements for example) so I'm going to swap to writing scripts in Selenium WebDriver. 
To avoid the complexity of recreating all of these test cases from the ground up I plan on exporting my existing test cases in C# with NUnit and modifying the scripts from there. But the scripts spat out by the IDE are structured in a way I'm not familiar with.

Here's a script that I wrote from scratch, that should help explain my linear understanding:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject

{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
    }
}

class GoogleSuggest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://website.com/account/Login.aspx");

        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LoginForm$UserName"));

        query.SendKeys("username");

        query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("LoginForm$Password"));

        query.SendKeys("password");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        driver.FindElement(By.Name("LoginForm$Button1")).Click();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);


        action.ContextClick(driver.FindElement(By.Id("uielementid"))).Perform();


    }
}
```

That's a script I wrote that signs in to a website. What I understand about that script is that it starts up a Firefox instance with the lines

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
```

It has a Main where the application starts, then using referential commands it starts up Firefox. **please correct me if I'm wrong here**

However, when I export cases from the IDE into C# with the NUnit Framework and copy it into a test project in VS I can't find where to put my Main to make the program compilable. The test case reads:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Login
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://website.com/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheLoginTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/account/Login.aspx");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_UserName")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_UserName")).SendKeys("username");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_Password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_Password")).SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginForm_Button1")).Click();
        }
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText() {
            try {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert) {
                    alert.Accept();
                } else {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            } finally {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've not been able to find where to insert my Main in this test case, nor (perhaps more importantly) do I understand this structure.

Any help or feedback is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The scripts exported from SelIDE assume xUnit framework. In the case of C# it is nUnit. http://www.nunit.org/

Comment: @SiKing thank you, do you know of anywhere I could go to learn about the nUnit framework and how to use it? I couldn't find anything on google - ultimately right now I need to know where to insert "_static void Main(string[] args)_"

Comment: Start here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=getStarted&r=2.6.4 There is **not** going to be a `Main()`!

Comment: Oh, that would explain why I haven't be able to use one ;) You've been very helpful, thank you. :)